# Want to send form json data to other server

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, http-post, form-submit

I have form that outputs data in json using angular there is no database. Now whatever is the output of that form I want to send it to some server Here is the code say I want to send it to server 192.80.36.4 for example. How to do it using post

```
 controller definition code 


<body ng-app="submitExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.list = [];
     $scope.text = '';
     $scope.submit = function() {
     if ($scope.text) {
      $scope.list.push(this.text);
      $scope.text = '';
    }
   };
  }]);
     </script>

  </script>
  <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
        Enter latitude:
        <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        <pre>list={{list| json}}</pre>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `$http` service:

```
angular.module('submitExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.list = [];
    $scope.text = '';
    $scope.submit = function() {
      if ($scope.text) {
        $scope.list.push(this.text);
        $scope.text = '';
        $http.post("<your-url>", $scope.list).success(function(data, status) {
          console.log(data);
        })
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: url of server that i want to send data to?

Comment: I don't know where you have to send your data. You need a server able to catch your POST requests.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://183.000.00.00/t/db/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
 this is error

Comment: it seems post request not a json type ,it XML